# How to select and change text using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors, selectors-api, innertext

I need to select text, which is contains in div, and change it to another text, from my example.

HTML source of the page, is look like this

```
<div itemprop="articleBody">    
  <div id="example">
    <h3 class="togg">Contacts</h3>
    My text to select <br />
    <img src="image" alt="new map" />
  </div>
</div>
```

So I need to find "My text to select" and change it to "New specific text"
I and write this script below, using document.querySelector, but it does not find anything

```
<script>
document.querySelector('div[itemprop=articleBody]’).innerHTML = 'New specific text';
</script>
```

Can you help me please with correct one?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: But also that's not jQuery. Please be sure which one you're using, they're not the same thing.